# How to DRY scope methods used in two different classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, dry

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to retrieve / scope associated objects by "specifying" / "filtering on" an attribute value on those associated objects. That is, at this time I am using the following code:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search_by_title(search)
    where('articles.title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  end
end

class ArticleAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search_by_article_title(search)
    joins(:article).where('articles.title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

In the above code the `where('articles.title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")` clause is repeated twice and so I thought that it may be improved with the DRY principle: *is it possible to use the* `Article.search_by_title` *method directly in the* `ArticleAssociation.search_by_article_title` *method?*

---

Typical use cases are:

- `ArticleAssociation.search_by_article_title("Sample string")`
- `Article.search_by_title("Sample string")`

Comment: I faced this same situation in a project (4 related models) and I created a module to hold the common search methods. Ut's not exactly what you ask for but it's a typical solution.

Comment: Code shared between classes usually ends up in a module

Comment: by they way, squeel's sifters can be used to this, but using squeel instead of AR is a big change.. https://github.com/ernie/squeel#sifters

Comment: @tokland - Can you provide an example implementation of making that in a module?

Comment: @apneadiving: Not always. In this case, we have two (what seem to be) related classes the just don't happen to have an inheritance relationship. When it is shared between some classes and it is *specific* to those classes, I'd put it in the class. Does a specific database query string deserve a module of it's own?

Comment: That's why I said "usually". If you only have this common code, don't add an extra module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you change the code structure completely, no.

You could do some hacking with lambdas, but that would be more code then the code you're DRYing. There is a such thing as good refactoring, and a such thing as bad refactoring. Unless a piece of *very* complex or long code is used in 2 or more places, then you can worry about refactoring. Code conventions are important, but for tiny one-method-call things like that its a waste and will probably make your code more cryptic.

Though, I know that it's annoying when people don't answer your question, so here:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  SEARCH_BY_TITLE=lambda {|obj, search| obj.where('articles.title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")}
  def self.search_by_title(search)
    SEARCH_BY_TITLE.call(self, search)
  end
end

class ArticleAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search_by_article_title(search)
    Article::SEARCH_BY_TITLE.call(joins(:article),search)
  end
end
```

That just makes a lambda as a constant that performs the `where` call on a specified object. Both methods just wrap that lambda.

Note: Although this may be considered more elegant, it will decrease  performance a lot, as lambdas, closures, and the extra call are expensive in a dynamic language like Ruby. But I don't think that's an issue for you.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.n - Thanks for your answer. However, I have *a lot of places where I need to use the code* `where('articles.title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")` and, even if you said "for tiny one-method-call things like that its a waste and will probably make your code more cryptic", *is it bad to repeat that code everywhere in my classes?*

Comment: @Backo: If you use the code a lot, the lambda is probably a better idea. If you use it only twice, as in the example, you're better repeating.

Answer (score 1):

As per OP request, I post the code that I wrote for a 3-module search using a module:

```
module Listable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    # Search a listable module search in properties (or related) tables
    def search_from_properties(string)
      return where({}) if string.blank?
      associations = self.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name) &
        [:property, :properties, :supplier, :suppliers, :address]
      s = "%#{string}%"
      associations.inject(self, :includes).where(
        ((Address[:base] =~ s) | (Address[:city] =~ s)) |
        ((Property[:owner] =~ s) | (Property[:cif] =~ s)) | 
        ((Supplier[:cups] =~ s) | (Supplier[:contract] =~ s))
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Now just include this module in the related classes:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Listable
end
```

Note: All models have associations defined to reach the other ones (that's why the `joins` work). Also, it uses [this wrapper over AR](https://gist.github.com/1333253).